# How to automate the android phone back button using appium

Tags: android, python, navigation, ui-automation, appium

I am working on test automation for a hybrid mobile application on Android using Appium(python client library). I haven't been able to figure out any means to automate or create a gesture for using the Phone back button to go back to the previous page of the app. Is there any driver function that can be used? I tried my luck with self.driver.navigate().back() [hoping this would simulate the same behaviour as in Selenium to navigate to the previous URL] but to no avail. Can anyone suggest a way out?

Comment: the self.driver.back() is the simplest solution.

Comment: possible its this issue https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4742 it recommends setting  unicodeKeyboard to False

Answer (score 15):

Yes,try the `driver.back()`, it simulates the system `back` function.

Comment: I tried but it's not working for me. Currently, I am using appium 2.2.3 please help

Answer (score 14):

I guess maybe it depends on what version of the client library are you using because in Java `driver.navigate().back()` works well.

Comment: Yes, it works well. Thanks Kristaps Mezavilks

Answer (score 6):

Recently I was automating one of the Native application where I had to click on back button.

I tried below code and it worked for me.

Code for Android back button.

```
driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

This will click on back button

Answer (score 2):

I used a KeyEvent.

```java
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;

driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent().withKey(AndroidKey.BACK));
```

Answer (score 1):

For appium-python-client, to go back you should call this method:

driver.press_keycode(4)

Answer (score 0):

driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);

does the job in Java

Comment: There is no such method in Java

Answer (score 0):

It may be late but useful
To click `android` device `back button` following line will help you.

```
helper.driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);
```

To click `android` recent apps button following line will help you.

```
helper.driver.pressKeyCode(187);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using back(),

```
self.driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

you use this code for python.

```
driver.press_keycode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this one it works 100%

```
driver.pressKeyCode(4);
```

as "4" is the key note for Back press on Android

Comment: The question is for an appium-python client.