# Appium Native View, how to click the button to go back to the previous screen

Tags: android, navigation, appium, back, android-uiautomator

I am pretty new to Appium, using UIAutomator2. Following instructions on the links:

[https://discuss.appium.io/t/click-back-button-on-android-device-in-java/6817/3][1]
[https://discuss.appium.io/t/click-back-button-twice-in-android-7-using-appium-uiautomator2/20368][2]
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801879/how-to-automate-the-android-phone-back-button-using-appium][3]

I have tried all the options offered in these articles:

> driver.pressKeyCode(4);
>
> helper.driver.pressKeyCode(187);
>
> driver.back();
>
> driver.navigate().back();

If I add the imports

> import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.AndroidKey;
> import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent;
> and I try
> driver.pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.BACK);

Eclipse tells me that the method is undefined...

But none of them have worked. Is there anything I need to import or any additional classes I need to create? My driver only has methods for testing, such as close(), equals(), execute(), findElement()... but nothing like back(), or pressKeyCode() or navigate()(this one, probably, because it is not webView)... So, when I try to just type any of those methods, Eclipse either suggests to add a cast, or to create a class...

Please, Can anyone give me some more details on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The driver should be an Appium driver. And try to run on real device than emulators.

```
driver = new AppiumDriver<>(url, desiredCapabilities);
```

Comment: The driver was originally defined as: /n
AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);

Comment: Then mostly driver.navigate().back(); will work. Did you tried it on a real device ?

Comment: The driver declaration is  ` AppiumDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(url, cap);` I've tried yours, but it still won't work...